# How to unpack a downloaded tar.bz2 archive?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I downloaded YOONO-Desktop from http://www.yoono.com/, and I try to install it with the following steps:

```
[root@localhost mpatil]# tar xfv yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar
tar: yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[root@localhost mpatil]# tar xfv yoono-destop-1.8.43
tar: yoono-destop-1.8.43: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This file is in Desktop/Ram/Downloads. But it is showing an error like "no such file or directory". Why is it showing this error?

Comment: clearly you are not aware of how to navigate in linux. 
Check this links: http://linuxcommand.org/lts0020.php and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_For_Newbies/Command_Line. They will help you understand how to navigate in the command line.

Comment: In CentOS 7 bzip2 does not come preinstalled, so you'd need `yum -y install bzip2` The error "file not found" is a bit deceiving.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to show *exactly* the commands you run and the corresponding output. `tar xfv yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar` will obviously not work if the file is named `yoono-desktop-1.8.43‌​.tar.bz2`. Also the `f` option should be immediately followed by the path to the file.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds from your description that your file is tar wrapped in bzip2. The following should work:

```
# You can omit the `j` on newer versions of tar
tar jxf yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
```

It also looks like you're in the wrong directory, either go to the correct directory, or pass its full path to tar.

Comment: this file in Desktop/RAM/Downloads.how to mention this path? and where to mention this path please suggest me...

Comment: @user2854207 `tar jxf ~/Desktop/RAM/Downloads/yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar.bz2`

Comment: it showing error again like tar (child): `/root/Desktop/RAM/Downloads/yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: @Chris please help me..

Comment: @user2854207 The error message is pretty self explanatory -- the file doesn't exist. It's not an issue with tar. Check your spelling and capitalisation, and, of course, that it really exists where you think.

Comment: this is my file location /home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2

Comment: i tried tar jxf ~/home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2

Comment: it is showing same error [root@localhost mpatil]#  tar jxf ~/home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
`tar (child): /root/home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: @user2854207 You're looking at /root/home, not /home, because you're running as root instead of the user owning the section of /home that the file is located inside (and even then, it would just be `~foo/bar`, not `~/home/foo/bar`. Explicitly specify the path.

Comment: @chris ya am running in root path.Explicitly specify the path means what? am not getting

Comment: Sorry, I don't have interest in continuing from here. I would just be repeating what I've already said from here on in. Please read what has been said again.

Answer (score 2):

You get `No such file or directory` error because you are logged in a root shell. The home directory of root (`/root/`) is different by yours (which in your case probably is `/home/mpatil/`).

So try with:

```
tar jxf /home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
```

To be sure 100% about the full path of `yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2` file, first run as root the following command:

```
updatedb
```

Then run:

```
locate yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
```

which will give you the full path of that archived file.

Or you can use `find`:

```
find /home -type f -name yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
```

Comment: You can see from the prompt they are in the home directory, not `/root`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you had good answers, my case was different which I want to share with you...

I needed to extract bz2 in **shared hosting** where `tar` couldnt help me to extract (got error with bzip2 and lbzip2, and I could not install anything or do sudo...)

I solved it by creating a php file and run it from command line (of course you can modify the script to use it online too).

**bunzip2.php**

```
<?php
function decompress($data)
 {
     // Decompress the file
     if (@file_exists($data)) {
         $bz = bzopen($data, 'r');
         $uncompressed = '';
         // Read the uncompressed data.
         while (!feof($bz)) {
             $uncompressed .= bzread($bz, 4096);
         }
         // Close the Bzip2 compressed file and write
         // the data to the uncompressed file.
         bzclose($bz);
         if (stripos($data, '.tbz2') !== false) {
             $newFile = str_replace('.tbz2', '.tar', $data);
         } else {
             if (stripos($data, '.tbz') !== false) {
                 $newFile = str_replace('.tbz', '.tar', $data);
             } else {
                 $newFile = str_replace('.bz2', '', $data);
             }
         }
         file_put_contents($newFile, $uncompressed);
         return $newFile;
         // Else, decompress the string
     } else {
         return bzdecompress($data);
     }
 }

decompress($argv[1]);
?>
```

> php bunzip2.php my.tar.bz2

(I just searched for bz2+php on github, I did not check the code in detail but it does the work ;)

Answer (score -2):

you can try install bzip2 by command: `yum install bzip2 -y` (Centos) and extract again: `tar -xjvf yoono-destop-1.8.43.tar.bz2`